If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, then it is algebraic over any extension field $L$ of $F$.
The photo attached is from the book Abstract Algebra by Dummit&Foote.
I didn’t understand it at all. How do we know that $L$ contains the element $\alpha$. In other words, what does $\alpha $ have to do with an arbitrary extension $L$ of $F$?

$\alpha$ being algebraic means it is the root of a polynomial in $F[X]$. If $L$ is an extension of $F$ then $F[X]\subseteq L[X]$. Does this answer your question?

$L$ does not contain the element $\alpha\in K$, but you are right to be confused. This text is badly written. The authors should state explicitely the assumption $F\subseteq L\subseteq K$.
